# How to find the max value inside a multiple key array?

Tags: javascript

I have here my router to get the values from my mongodb while checking its total sum:

```
router.get('/bloodinventory', function(req, res) {
      Bloodinventory.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$blood_category" , count :{$sum:"$num_stock"}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, inventory) {     
      res.json({ success: true, inventory: inventory });
    });  
});
```

Then in my controller i have this function to initialize it to my charts:

```
function getChart() {

    Bloodinventory.getChart().then(function(data) {
        console.log(1, data.data.inventory);
        app.inventory = data.data.inventory; 
        initChart();      
    });
}
```

Here is the sample output of my console:

```
[{_id: "aspheresis platelets", count: 264} 
 {_id: "cryoprecipitate",count: 330}]
```

My question is, how can I get the max value of count inside the inventory array?

Comment: Do you just want the number, or do you want the whole object whose count is the highest in the list?

Comment: just the number sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `.reduce()` function of an array very easily, like so:

The idea is to keep track of the object with the highest count and compare it to each of the items in the list. The reduce function will return the item with the largest count when it has gone through the entire list. Similarly, in the second example below, you can just grab the number by using `Math.max()` to compare all of the counts.

```js
var data = [
  {_id: "item1", count: 300},
  {_id: "item2", count: 265},
  {_id: "item3", count: 410},
  {_id: "item4", count: 115},
  {_id: "item5", count: 395},
];

var highestCountObject = data.reduce((res, item) => item.count > res.count ? item : res, {count: -Infinity});

console.log(highestCountObject);

var highestNumber = Math.max(...data.map(item => item.count));

console.log(highestNumber);
```

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera Great! Glad it worked for you `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop keep track of max value in a variable.

```js
let obj = [{_id: "aspheresis platelets", count: 264},{_id: "cryoprecipitate",count: 330}]

let max = -Infinity

for( let i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
  if(obj[i].count > max) {
    max = obj[i].count; 
  } 
}
console.log(max)
```

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it in descending order. and than access count of `0th` index element.

```js
let obj = [{_id: "aspheresis platelets", count: 264},{_id: "cryoprecipitate",count: 330}]
 
let op = obj.sort((a,b)=> b.count-a.count)[0].count
 
console.log(op)
```

Comment: This is O(nlog(n)), you can do this in O(n)

Comment: @mhodges here you go `o(n)` solution. check

Comment: Looks good. I think a good old fashioned for loop is the most efficient solution of all of them.